# Rails application and jQuery use-cases?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a Rails (4.2.1) application which is using scriptaculous and prototype ...

Now I want to migrate to Jquery ... what would be the best way?

using this gem: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails

or adding the sources in public folder?

When using the gem ... how do I use it? I haven't got this

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

like it's mentioned in installation guide? ...

Comment: You can create `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file and Rails 4 should automatically pick it up. Then you need to write this: `//= require jquery` in your file after adding jquery-rails gem in your Gemfile and running `bundle install`. Did you do that before asking this question?

Comment: Hi no I haven't done this. I wanted to know what the advanteges are when I use the gem instead of putting jquery.js in public folder

Comment: There's no advantage, it's a matter of preference. Sure, you can download the jquery file and put it in `app/assets/javascripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js` and then in application.js: `//= require jquery-2.1.4.min`.

Comment: @Felix better you should put the jquery-2.1.4.min.js in vendor folder. Third party libraries should be inside of vendor directory

Comment: @kamesh : Rails 4 has deprecated and discourage the usage of vendor directory.

Comment: the advantage of a gem is that you can manage updates like you do with all other gems.